# How to find most common phrases in a list of senetences using a hash table

Tags: c, hash

All sentences are in small case english with no punctuation marks and a phrase is defined as 3 consecutive words so 
if a sentence is : i am jessica hunt

so the phrases would be "i am jessica" and "am jessica hunt"

a phrase is common if its present in all sentences of the file

Kindly help me with an appropiate hash function for this problem

Comment: You're definition above does not include the specification for termination of a *'sentence'*; you only specify what a 'phrase' is. Also, this problem is as much about data grouping as it is about hashing, so you'll need to consider that as significant in solving your problem.

Comment: Sentence terminates after an endline 
so 
hello how are you
ok this is cool

are 2 sentences

Answer (score 1):

Anything goes. I would start with (3*a + 5*b + 7*c) with {a,b,c} being the wordnumbers (or hash values) of the three consecutive words. (ofcourse all unsigned, and modulo wordsize)

- tokenise into words, ignoring the whitespace and punctuation
- put the resulting words into a hash table (dict)
- step through the file, maintaining a sliding window for computing the three-token hashes
- and put/update these into a second hashtable.
- for collision resolution, this second hashtable needs to have (pointers,indexes) access to the originating three words.

Answer (score 0):

Jessica,
I guess you need a n-gram hasher not sentence one (which is almost the same).
I have written in C a superfast n-gram ripper freely downloadable at:
http://www.sanmayce.com/Downloads/index.html#Leprechaun

Leprechaun would rip the "sentence" 'i am jessica hunt' down to these two 3-grams:
i_am_jessica
am_jessica_hunt

Perhaps n-gramming is your thing as well.